# cross apply giving missing keyword error

Tags: oracle, plsql, cross-apply

Below query is giving missing keyword error..

```
select * 
  from its_account aac 
 CROSS APPLY its.fnGetAccountIdentifier(aac.account_key) ;
```

here is my function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION fnGetAccountIdentifier
(
  v_AccountKey IN NUMBER
)
RETURN fnGetAccountIdentifier_pkg.tt_fnGetAccountIdentifier_type PIPELINED
AS
   v_temp SYS_REFCURSOR;
   v_temp_1 TT_FNGETACCOUNTIDENTIFIER%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
   OPEN v_temp FOR
      SELECT * 
        FROM tt_fnGetAccountIdentifier;

   LOOP
      FETCH v_temp INTO v_temp_1;
      EXIT WHEN v_temp%NOTFOUND;
      PIPE ROW ( v_temp_1 );
   END LOOP;
END;
```

I do not know where I am doing wrong. I am really new to this.

Comment: I thought you might mean [cross join](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55316), but that doesn't seem right. Oracle doesn't have `APPLY`. Assuming `tt__fnGetAccountIdentifier` has an `account_key` field, why aren't you just joining those two table together with a normal inner join? If you really want the function you can join to `table(its.fnGetAccountIdentifier)` on the key - you aren't using the key value you're passing in at the moment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The `APPLY` SQL syntax, whether it `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` was introduced in

   Oracle 12c version. Prior versions of Oracle RDBMS do not support `APPLY` SQL syntax.
2. When selecting from table function you need to use `TABLE()` function:

Having said that, you could rewrite your query as follows:

*For 12c* using `cross apply`.

```
 select * 
   from its_account aac 
  cross apply TABLE(fnGetAccountIdentifier(aac.account_key)) ;
```

*For 9i* and up using `cross join`.

```
 select * 
   from its_account aac 
  cross join TABLE(fnGetAccountIdentifier(aac.account_key)) ;
```

In your case there is no difference - you will get the same result using `cross join` as you would using `cross apply`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want a cross join, as I think you're expecting the table to be effectively joined to the results of the pipelined function based on the `account_key`. But that's also assuming that column exists in both tables. It's a bit unclear, not least because you aren't using the `account_key` you're passing to the function.

So I *think* you want a normal inner join, using the `table` operator to treat your pipelined function results as a table:

```
select * 
  from its_account aac 
 JOIN table(fnGetAccountIdentifier(aac.account_key)) t
 ON t.account_key = aac.account_key ;
```

But there's a lot of speculation in there. Here's [an SQL Fiddle showing the results of that join and a cross join](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9e11/1); the cross join output doesn't look useful, but only you can really know that, since I've made the data up.