# Cross apply missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a query in Oracle(11g):

```
  select DBTM,AVNR from E_MW_01Min_MIT m
  cross apply(
        select Avnr,XDatum1 from E_MW_01DAY_MEX d
        where  d.AVnr = m.avnr
        and    d.XDatum1 = m.DBTM 
   )
```

but it gives me the error

```
   ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

where is the problem?
Thank you

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: The OUTER APPLY/CROSS APPLY constructs are supported in Oracle starting with v.12c

Answer (score 2):

This keywords (CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY) is introduced in Oracle 12c version. 
You can see this link : 
[cross apply giving missing keyword error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270543/cross-apply-giving-missing-keyword-error)

Answer (score 1):

`cross apply` is not available in that version of Oracle. Just use `join` instead:

```
select m.DBTM, d.AVNR
from E_MW_01Min_MIT m JOIN
     E_MW_01DAY_MEX d
     ON  d.AVnr = m.avnr AND d.XDatum1 = m.DBTM ;
```

This is actually more easily expressed using `JOIN`, so I see no advantage to attempting `APPLY` even if the database does support it.